# Clique numbers of chordal graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $c_i$ be the number of complete subgraphs of size $i$ in a graph $G$. I learned the following result:

If $G$ has $n$ vertices and is connected and chordal, that is, $G$ does not have induced cycles of length at least 4, then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} c_i = 1
$$

See for example Thm 4.1 (together with the fact that $\lambda=1$ is a root after Theorem 3.1) in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X02005009), or Prop 2.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3416.pdf).

My question is the following:

1. Is there an elementary proof of this fact without resorting to topological arguments?
2. Is there a generalization of this to k-chordal graphs?

Comment: Should we assume that $G$ is connected, or, the same thing, replace RHS to the number of connected components?

Comment: Yes, in general that would be c_0. I have added the connectedness assumption. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another argument. A chordal graph has a *perfect elimination
ordering* $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of its vertices. This means that the
neighbors among $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$ of $v_i$ form a clique $C_i$ . See
for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph. If $C_i$ has
$p_i$ vertices, then we obtain ${p_i\choose j}$ new cliques of size
$j+1$ when we adjoin the vertex $v_i$ to the subgraph spanned by
$v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$. If $G$ is connected then $p_i>0$ when $i>1$, so $\sum
(-1)^{j}{p_i\choose j}=0$. Hence the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}c_i$ is
equal to the contribution from adjoining the first vertex $v_1$,
namely, 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. In an attempt to consider what subgraph count identities might hold for k-chordal graphs (k=3 for chordal), I found the PEO property is extended here: sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X13003877 which basically says the neighbors among the previous vertices are within distance k-2 of each other. It seems if we replace c_i by the numbers of i-cliques in G^{k-2}, the same argument does NOT go through, and I am not sure what are the correct subgraph counts to look at here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove that in a chordal graph we have $s(G):=c_1-c_2+c_3-\dots=c_0$, where $c_0$ denotes the number of connected components. Assume the contrary and let $G$ be a minimal (in the sense of number of vertices) counterexample. Then $G$ is connected and has at least two vertices. Let $v$ be such a vertex that $G-v$ is connected. The key fact is that the graph induced on the 1-neighborhood $N(v)$ is also connected. Indeed, if $N(v)=A\sqcup B$ with non-empty $A,B$ and there are no edges between $A$ and $B$, then consider the minimal path in $G-v$ from some $a\in A$ to $b\in B$. Adding the edges $va,vb$ to this path we get a chordless cycle. Well, now $s(G)=s(G-v)-s(N(v)-v)+1=1$ (the first summand corresponds to complete subgraphs not containing $v$, the second to complete subgraphs containing $v$ and something else, the third to $\{v\}$.) $G$ is not a counterexample, contradiction.

Comment: It maybe too late, but can you explain $s(G)=s(G-v)-s(G[N(v)-v])+1$ part little bit more?

Comment: @okw1124 I have brief explanations for all three summands, which of them needs to be explained more?

Comment: Intuitively, I understood that adding $v$ makes $(r-1)$-cliques in $G[N(v)-v]$ to $r$-cliques in $G$. But how can I prove this concretely? Should I focus on the fact that $N(v)$ makes a clique, and adding $v$ to $N(v)$ makes a clique with one more vertex?

Comment: @okw1124 $N(v)$ is not a clique, but any clique containing $v$ has a form "$v$ plus some clique in $N(v)-v$", and viceversa

Comment: I thought that since the distance between any two vertices in $N(v)$ is $1$, $N(v)$ makes a clique. Did I miss something?